# Запятая перед сравнением

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, сравнительный-оборот, сравнение

> Он работал(,) как его отец: усердно и не жалея себя.

Нужна ли запятая на месте скобок? Я думаю, нужна, вот моя аргументация: в роли обобщающего слова при однородных обстоятельствах «усердно и не жалея себя» будет выступать сочетание «как его отец». И если его выделить запятыми как сравнительный оборот, то, следовательно, данный оборот будет обозначать только уподобление. Но в этом предложении слова «как его отец», так как являются обобщающими, должны обнаруживать общее обстоятельств «усердно и не жалея себя», соответственно, должны иметь значение обстоятельства и потому не выделяться запятыми.

Верна ли моя логика? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: «Если его выделить запятыми как сравнительный оборот» — аналогичная фраза?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекст приходится придумывать. Если в предложение есть сравнение с отцом, то эта тема **уже начата** в предыдущем тексте, например:

*Его отец отличался особенным трудолюбием. И ***О***н работал, **как его отЕц**: усЕрдно и не жалея себЯ.*

Сравнительный оборот здесь **нельзя не обособить.** Это именно **сравнение,** а не обстоятельство образа действия с конкретным содержанием.

Обособленный оборот не может быть обобщающим словом по своей грамматике, но он занимает **позицию обобщающего слова**, сравнить:   *И **О**н работал **по-отцовски**: усЕрдно и не жалея себЯ.*

Однородный ряд более полно раскрывает (поясняет) содержание выражений ***как отец, по-отцовски.***

Comment: Очень обстоятельный ответ, но всё-таки я не до конца понял Вашу логику: если можно заменить на «по-отцовски», т.е. на наречие образа действия,  почему нужно обособлять, ведь это главный фактор, указывающий на отсутствие обособления?

Comment: Это следует из контекста. Нельзя рассматривать предложение изолированно. Необособленный сравнительный оборот должен быть самодостаточным по содержанию, например: Тропинка вьется как змея. Для этого оборота контекста не нужно, его смысл и так понятен. А  у оборота "как его отец" нет самодостаточного качественного признака, поэтому он может быть только сравнением. Такой же сравнительный смысл  и в наречии по-отцовски, но там другая грамматика (слово, а не оборот).